# Why did Tom Riddle's face become hideous?

Tags: character, harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, it is shown that Voldemort is Tom Riddle who is actually a handsome fellow. But in the next movies, we see that Voldemorte's face becomes weird / hideous. Why does it happen?

Is it because of the *Horcruxes*? Or something else?

Comment: In part, yes. But as far as we know, it was the collective productive of all the dark arts he dabbled with, including but not limited to horcruxes. They took a toll on his physical appearance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the Harry Potter Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Tom_Riddle#Lord_Voldemort.27s_request):

> While working at Borgin and Burkes, Tom befriended Hepzibah Smith, a
>   wealthy but elderly descendant of Helga Hufflepuff. Between 1955 and
>   1961, Hepzibah showed Tom her two most valuable treasures: his
>   ancestor's locket and her ancestor's cup. Tom's eyes flashed red with
>   greed and avarice upon seeing these objects and he desired them,
>   because he saw the locket to be rightfully his as Slytherin's heir and
>   the cup was a reminder of Hogwarts as well as a priceless artefact.
>   Tom killed Hepzibah to steal these coveted objects and vanished
>   without a trace.
>
> [...]
>
> Tom disappeared for ten long years. He slipped deeper into the Dark
>   Arts, travelled extensively, consorted with disreputable people, **began
>   to become distorted in appearance and lost his handsomeness, due to
>   splitting his soul so many times**, and began to use the alias "Lord
>   Voldemort" openly.

Comment: probably better to actually quote the books

Comment: @BCdotWEB Is there any exact reason?

Comment: @AsifIqubal I haven't read the books, so I don't know. Ask on the SF&F SE, plenty of Potter experts there. Books are out of scope here anyway. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter

Answer (score -3):

No, it was because he made spells to change his appearence in order to be a distinct figure in the magic world and he also did not want to look like his hated human father and his weak mother.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you had quotes to back it up.